# Javascript redirect before the rest of the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, iphone, redirect, safari

I am making an iPhone webapp with a login form. Once the user is logged in I am storing some information in an HTML5 DB.

The problem is that every time the app is loaded the `login.php` page runs and checks if there is some info in the DB, if there is, it redirects to `data.php`, but in the meantime I see a short buy annoying flash of login.php.

I am placing the code that checks the DB on top of the page with a `window.stop()` after it, but no luck.

Any point in the right direction will be much appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: Where do you check for login info in DB? I mean is it on `window.onload` or `Ext.onReady`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the checking in login.php (and handle the redirect) before you display anything, not after displaying the page.

Comment: so you mean like a new page login.js wich will check if there is a db or not and then redirects? Nice idea.